# TexMaker exits when typing

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu, bugs, software

I am using TexMaker 5.02 on an Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and the program exits regularly for unknown reasons. I realized after several occurences of these exits it coincided with me typing the characters "exa" at a regular pace. I try to avoid using words such as "examples" or "exactly" but I forget this rule too quickly so I figured I could ask there.

I wondered if maybe the software had some hidden mnemonics I can set differently. For full disclosure I am using an AZERTY keyboard so maybe the "a" is wrongly interpreted as a "q" but even so I do not understand why it would acts this way.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Pierre, I'm quite new here too but I think this is not the right place to ask your question. TeX.SE is for LaTeX questions not for things around LaTeX. I guess your best bet is the [TeXMaker contact form](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/index_fr.html#contact). Side comment: after some time using TexMaker, I found myself way more comfortable using TeXStudio, although, this is a personal feeling.

Comment: My texmaker work fine. Look like a corrupted/outdated installation/configuration, or a  bug. Run it from the console to see if the accidental exit produce some ominous message as  "segmentation fault".

Comment: I thank you for your two answers, I will switch to TeXStudio which seems to work nicely instead of srtuggling to find the bug